# How to add a custom operator in delphi?

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to add a custom operator in Delphi 6?
for example: a:=b **myoperator** c;
and define its precedence?
Thanks

Comment: You are seeking to **introduce a new, distinct operator**, right? That's not possible in Delphi at all.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define operators. You can overload existing operators, such as addition,  subtraction, multiplication etc. But only in more recent Delphi versions, from Delphi 2006, but not in Delphi 6.

You cannot specify operator precedence. That is fixed by the language specification.  Even when you overload operators their precedence is the same as the built-in operators.

Answer (score 3):

In Delphi 6, you can't overload operators at all, sorry.

But even in newer versions that support operator overloading, you can only overload the existing operators, and these keep their operator precendence.

Note that in most versions that support it, this is only possible on records. Only in some of the newer (mobile) compilers with ARC, you can overload operators on classes too.

But again, you can't define *new* operators.

If, by any chance, you mean Delphi **XE6**, then take a look at: [Operator overloading (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)). That explains operator overloading for Delphi 10 Seattle, but it is the same for XE6.

Comment: There was [operator overloading for variants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Implementing_Binary_Operations) in D6, by the way.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: yes, could be. For me, it is too long ago to remember. But not in Delphi 5, I guess.

Comment: @danmatei: Bad? Note that Delphi 5 was released 17 years ago, which is more than a century in computer years. Currently, you can get the [latest Delphi (but only the Starter version) for free](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter/promotional-download).